# Using an inputted string as a default text appearing in SwiftUI's TextField

Tags: ios, swiftui, mobile-application, xcode11, swift5

This is a simple `struct` involving `TextField` which works fine.

```
struct NewProjectView: View {
    @State var name = ""
    @State var lastName = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Name: ", text: $name)
            TextField("Last Name: ", text: $lastName)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have modified the `struct` to accept two parameters, and trying to make them equal to the `@State` variables.

```
struct NewProjectView: View {
    var oldName: String
    var oldLastName: String        

    @State var name = oldName // ERROR
    @State var lastName = oldLastName // ERROR

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Name: ", text: $name)
            TextField("Last Name: ", text: $lastName)
        }
    }
}

struct NewProjectView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewProjectView(oldName: "James", oldLastName: "Morton")
    }
}
```

However, error appears as follow

> Cannot use instance member 'oldName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

The I put `self.` in front of `oldName` and `oldLastName`, another appears,

> Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

At this point I have no idea what to do. I expect name and last name to be shown in both `TextField`s.

Answer (score 2):

If this view is intended to change name and last name then you need `@Binding`, not a `@State`

Like in

```
struct NewProjectView: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    @Binding var lastName: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Name: ", text: $name)
            TextField("Last Name: ", text: $lastName)
        }
    }
}
```

so creating it you can pass into old name and last name, say from some model.